# Can you conclude that $A=B$ if $A,B$ and $C$ are sets such that...

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

We've just learnt sets, and I'm having a little trouble understanding. So I have set up three examples which my answers. Only I'm not sure if they are correct, and would like someone to confirm if they are or not so I can continue to study without practicing all the questions incorrectly.

If they are incorrect, I would love a point in the right direction! They are "yes" or "no" answers.

Can you conclude that $A=B$ if $A,B$ and $C$ are sets such that...

Ex 1: $\bar A \cap C = \bar B \cap C$
My answer: no.

Ex 2. $A\cup C = B\cup C$
my answer: yes.

Ex 3. $A\times C = B \times C$
my answer: yes.

Comment: 2. Let $A = B \cup C$.

Answer (score 4):

1. Your answer is correct. An example is $A=\{0\}$, $B=\{1\}$, and $C=\varnothing$, with universal set $U=\{0,1\}$; then $\bar A\cap C=\{1\}\cap\varnothing=\varnothing=\{0\}\cap\varnothing=\bar B\cap C$, but $A\ne B$.
2. Here’s you’re wrong. For an example you can use the same $A,B$, and $U$ as in (1), but take $C=\{0,1\}$: $A\cup C=C=B\cup C$, but $A\ne B$.
3. Here you’re right **provided that** $C\ne\varnothing$. If $C\ne\varnothing$, let $c\in C$. Then for each $a\in A$ we have $\langle a,c\rangle\in A\times C=B\times C$, so $a\in B$, and therefore $A\subseteq B$. A similar argument shows that $B\subseteq A$, so $A=B$. However, if $C=\varnothing$, then $A\times C=\varnothing=B\times C$ no matter what $A$ and $B$ are.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "no" to all of them. For two of the examples, it helps to consider $C=\emptyset$. For the other, it helps to let $C=A\cup B$.